# Syntax error on token "msopenfile", delete this token

Tags: java

Here is my code. I am Relatively new to java but why am I getting the error: Syntax error on token "msopenfile", delete this token

If you need more code, just tell me, and ask questions through comments.

```
list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
                        JList list = (JList)evt.getSource();
                        if (evt.getClickCount() == 2) {

                            int index = list.locationToIndex(evt.getPoint());
                            System.out.println(model.get(index));
                            File msopenfile = new File(path+ "\\" +model.get(index));
                            Desktop.getDesktop().open(File msopenfile);
                            System.out.println(msopenfile);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here :

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(File msopenfile);
```

Replace it with :

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(msopenfile);
```

Comment: that gives me Unhandled exception type IOException, is it okay to surround with try and catch?

Comment: @Qwerty you must handle this exception. try/catch can be a good candidate depending on what you do in the catch. What do you want to do if the file does not exist?

Comment: Thanks, I see but I have a real file checker earlier in the code

Comment: @Qwerty then the case should never happen. Nevertheless, the Java syntax forces you to handle it anyway because `IOException` does not extend `RuntimeException`. In such case, I would maybe surround with try/catch and throw an `IllegalArgumentException` (which extends RuntimeException`) in the catch. Not sure if it is the best idea :p